# Are there (non Lagrangian) algebras of Turaev-Viro TQFTs which cannot be completed to Lagrangian algebras?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory, modular-tensor-categories, reshetikhin-turaev

Consider a 3d TQFT of the Turaev-Viro type, say TV$(\mathcal{C})$, where $\mathcal{C}$ is some fusion category. Equivalently, this is a TQFT admitting Lagrangian algebra objects $\mathcal{L}$ of the MTC $Z(\mathcal{C})$ (the Drinfeld center).

If this is simplifying the discussion you may assume the TQFT to be abelian, namely $\mathcal{C}=\text{Vec}_G^{\omega}$ for some finite abelian group $G$ and a cocycle $\omega\in H^3(G,U(1))$. In this case the TQFT is just a Dijkgraaf-Witten theory.

By an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ of the TQFT I mean an object of $Z(\mathcal{C})$ which is a connected commutative special Frobenius algebra (see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0204148). This is an object which can be condensed, and this produces a different TQFT where, very roughly speaking, we mod-out simple objects inside $\mathcal{A}$ and we also eliminate simple objects with non-trivial braiding with those inside $\mathcal{A}$, hence we only keep objects with trivial braiding with $\mathcal{A}$. The algebra is called Lagrangian if it is maximal, in the sense that there are no other simple objects which can be added keeping it to be an algebra. As a result, a Lagrangian algebra is characterized by the property that its condensation leads to the trivial TQFT.

Crucially, saying that the TQFT is of Turaev-Viro type is equivalent to say that it admits Lagrangian algebras. But now suppose that in the Turaev-Viro theory we consider an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ which is not Lagrangian. Is it possible that it is NOT a subalgebra of a Lagrangian algebra? This would be equivalent to say that the non-trivial TQFT obtained by condensing $\mathcal{A}$ does not admit Lagrangian algebras, hence it is not of the Turaev-Viro type.

At least in the abelian examples, where the TQFT is Dijkgraaf-Witten, it seems to me that this is never possible, just looking example by example. However I don't know a proof of this fact.

In the non-abelian case I don't really have a conjecture, but it seems very strange to me that one could produce a TQFT without Lagrangian algebras (like Chern-Simons TQFTs, or more generally chiral Reshetikhin–Turaev theories) from a TQFT with Lagrangian algebras, by gauging a non-Lagrangian algebra.

Is there something known?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is never possible. Indeed, if $A\in Z(\mathcal{C})$ is a condensable (connected, separable, commutative) algebra, then the condensed theory is $Z(\mathcal{C})_A^{\operatorname{loc}}$, which is equivalent to $Z(\mathcal{C}_A)$, the Drinfeld center of the fusion category $\mathcal{C}_A$ of right $A$-modules in $\mathcal{C}$. Since $Z(\mathcal{C}_A)$ is again a center, there is a Langrangian algebra $L_A$ in $\mathcal{C}_A$. Finally, there is a correspondence between Lagrangian algebras in $Z(\mathcal{C}_A)$ and Lagrangian algebras in $Z(\mathcal{C})$ over $A$. A reference for these facts is arXiv:1009.2117.